# C++ Threading : Attempt to use a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading, juce

Im making a MIDI generator in C++ using JUCE framework.
I'd like to do the generating in a different thread so it won't block my entire program. 
This is how I make my thread:

```
    std::thread generationThread (&MainContentComponent::generateProgression,var1, var2);
```

generateProgression is the function that generate's MIDI based on var1 (integer) and var2 (boolean)

The thread is created in the MainContentComponent class, and generateProgression is a function of that class.

The problem is that I'm getting a compile error saying : "Attempt to use a deleted function".
Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: "attempt to use a deleted function" is usually a clash between something attempting to use the copy constructor of a class that has been declared with the JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR macro which works by deleting the copy constructor.

Comment: Upvoted your question. Not sure why it had no votes, but it lead me here which helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why I got so many downvotes on this one.
Luckily a friend of mine told me what was wrong.
I needed to also give the current context.
As the thread is created in the class that also contains the function the context can just be "this".

```
    std::thread(&Fooclass::fooMainloopMemberFunction, context, argument);
```

or in my case

```
    std::thread generationThread (&MainContentComponent::generateProgression,this,var1, var2);
```

Comment: upvoted your question AND answer: kudos for taking time to answer your own question to help the rest of us